# How do I obtain an Access Token from an Unauthenticated Cognito Identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-credentials, aws-identitypools

I am dealing with a unauthenticated identity, via Cognito and the identity pool.

Here is what I am doing (*via Rest API calls*):

1. `AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId` -- to register the identity
2. `AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity` -- return credentials for the provided identity ID

What I am confused about, is this:

How can I covert the (temporary) AWS Credentials into an **Access Token** (so that I can perform calls against the AWS API Gateway)?

Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Btw, this is what I have, as my AWS Crendetials:

```
{
  "Credentials": {
    "AccessKeyId": "...",
    "Expiration": 1649299760,
    "SecretKey": "...",
    "SessionToken": "..."
  },
  "IdentityId": "ap-southeast-2:..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint should work even for unauthenticated users, then just let it without any authorizer.

The Unauthenticated Identity is just a phantom for a user, no one gets authenticated, so you can’t get any authentication token that would guarantee the same.

Comment: Maybe.. I am able to get the Openid Token, via a call to `AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetOpenIdToken`, this returned in JWT formate.  This would allow me to perform validation at the server side, but I see your point re a 'phantom' user.